# Why can we say that at zero absolute temperature is there only one accesible state?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

While studying the microcanonical ensemble, the entropy definition requires that at T=0 there is only one accesible state so that the entropy, S=0. Why is it true?

Comment: If zero-termperature quantum states can be degenerate, then it's not true. But that requires some kind of unbroken symmetry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109941/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: @ACuriousMind not the same question, thelast answer only takes he numbe of miscrostates as 1 but does not explain why

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299331/explicit-nontrivial-examples-in-quantum-mechanics-ground-state-degeneracy

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/260978/the-correct-statement-of-the-third-law-of-thermodynamics

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.

It is a typical misconception originating from a careless connection between statistical mechanics and thermodynamics. Thermodynamic behavior can be recovered from the ensemble approach to Statistical Mechanics only looking at the behavior of entropy, free energies, energy *per particle* or *per unit volume* at the so-called thermodynamic limit (by the way, only at the thermodynamic limit results derived in different ensembles become equivalent).

As a consequence, in order to have 
$$
s(u,v)=0
$$
where $u=U/N$, $v=V/N$, and $s=S/N$,
at the state where $\left( \frac{\partial s}{\partial u} \right)_u^{-1}=0$ (which is a statement equivalent to the third law) it is not necessary that $S=0$, but it is enough that it would not diverge with the size as fast as $N$. For example, a logarithmic divergence with $N$  of the ground state degeneracy would be perfectly compatible with the Planck's form of the third principle.